# Problem in one of the steps of training with data

Tags: python, machine-learning

So as I was learning one-hot encoding,the formation of w in `Aw = Y` :

```
#Training with Aw = Y
addlcol = lambda x: np.concatenate((x,np.ones((x.shape[0],1))),axis = 1)
Na, Nx = X_train.shape  # 120 ,4 #X_train is training data of iris dataset
XX = addlcol(X_train)
YY = Y_train
W = np.linalg.inv(XX.T.dot(XX)).dot(XX.T.dot(YY))
```

What is the use of `addlcol` function.I am not able to understand 
edit: why didn't X_train is directly used rather than concatenation it with ones

Comment: It adds a column of 1's on the left. That effectively adds a constant term to your linear model, allowing `np.linalg.inv` to find the best-fit constant-offset term in your regression. There's nothing specific to one-hot encoding in the question as far as I can see.

Comment: Understood and made the changes to the specified question